# Xdebug inside docker in PhpStorm doesn't work

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, docker-compose, xdebug

I have trouble getting xdebug to work inside docker on a remote VPS. Is this even possible? I have tried almost every possible combination of values but nothing seems to work.

I'd like to remotely debug a PHP app inside a docker container, more specifically Laradock. Is there something wrong in my configuration?

For the record, I've also opened my firewall to see if the problem lied there, PhpStorm is also listening for connections, but alas. Any help would be greatly appreciated... If I need to supply more info, I will gladly do so.

PhpStorm error
[image: PhpStorm error]

the docker containers
[image: docker containers]

PhpStorm settings
[image]

PhpStorm settings remote interpreter
[image]

xdebug in container runs
[image: Xdebug is loaded]

```
    ### Workspace Utilities Container ###########################

workspace:
    build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
            - INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
            - INSTALL_MONGO=false
            - INSTALL_NODE=true
            - INSTALL_YARN=false
            - INSTALL_DRUSH=false
            - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION=false
            - INSTALL_V8JS_EXTENSION=false
            - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=false
            - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=true
            - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=true
            - PUID=1000
            - PGID=1000
            - NODE_VERSION=stable
            - YARN_VERSION=latest
            - TZ=CET
    volumes_from:
        - applications
    extra_hosts:
        # IMPORTANT: Replace with your Docker Host IP (will be appended to
        - "dockerhost:192.168.128.3"
    ports:
       - "2222:22"
    tty: true

### PHP-FPM Container #######################################

php-fpm:
    build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
            - INSTALL_XDEBUG=true
            - INSTALL_SOAP=true
            - INSTALL_MONGO=false
            - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=true
            - INSTALL_BCMATH=false
            - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=false
            - INSTALL_OPCACHE=true
            - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE_EXTENSION=true
            - CODEIGNITER=false
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-70
    volumes_from:
        - applications
    expose:
        - "9000"
    links:
        - workspace
    extra_hosts:
        # IMPORTANT: Replace with your Docker Host IP (will be appended to
       - "dockerhost:192.168.128.3"
    environment:
    # IMPORTANT: Set the Remote Interpreter entry matching name to laravel
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=laravel
```

Comment: 1) Please fix your PHP startup warnings (last screenshot); 2) Please provide `phpinfo();` output (if you are trying to debug CLI scripts .. then capture it via CLI; if web page -- capture it via browser) -- I need to see top 2 able + whole xdebug section; 3) Show screenshot of xdebug settings in PhpStorm; 4) collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session and share it: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: So far it could be: 1) your xdebug uses the same 9000 port as php-fpm -- so it connects to that service instead of IDE 2) Wrong IP for `xdebug.remote_host` -- it must be an IP where IDE is running as seen from that remote machine (it's xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around)

Comment: *"xdebug to work inside docker on a remote VPS"* How "remote" it is? For site somewhere on internet you may need to use SSH tunnel for xdebug connection to be able to connect to your IDE .. or open appropriate port in your router & firewall.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, here is the output of the phpinfo() from the php-fpm container: http://pastebin.com/3823wvuz

The docker containers run on a VPS, phpstorm is my IDE here at home.
so xdebug.remote_host should be my home IP address? And I should change the port to something other than 9000 for xdebug?